# Writing Foldernames in a Array Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to write the directory names of several folders in an array. However, only all directory names with a date <today should be read. The directory names contain a date in this form * YYYYMMDD *

So I would have to do the following:

1. Borrow the date
2. Write the date in the form of YYYYMMDD in a variable
3. Read out directory names and check against the variable
   Write data to an array ... do something ...

Can someone tell me how I can solve this with Powershell please?

Thank you

Comment: Do these directorynames **start** with the date?. What do you mean by _Borrow the date_? Is that the date of today or what? Are the folders to kist all inside the same root folder? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64535030/edit) your question and add examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by retrieving all the candidate directories, then use `Where-Object` to extract the date part and test that it describes a date prior to today:

```
# Define threshold
$Today = (Get-Date).Date

# Go through all candidate directories
$oldDirectories = Get-ChildItem .\path\to\root\folder -Directory |Where-Object {
  $dt = 0
  # Test if directory name contains 8 consecutive digits describing a valid date 
  if($_.Name -match '(\d{8})' -and [datetime]::TryParseExact($Matches[1], 'yyyyMMdd', , $null, 'None', [ref]$dt)){
      # We only want the ones with a date prior to today
      $dt.Date -lt $today
  }
  else{
      # Not containing a properly formatted date, we're not interested
      $false
  }
}

# Now we can extract the names
$oldDirectoryNames = @($oldDirectories.Name) # or @($oldDirectories |Select -Expand Name)
```

Comment: I can not do anything with this script. It does nocht work.

Comment: @Diamond It will not output anything, but `$oldDirectoryNames` will contain your array of directory names afterwards

Comment: Yes, thats korrekt yes!

Comment: @Diamond If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

Do these directorynames start with the date?
yes
What do you mean by Borrow the date? Is that the date of today or what?
Determine the Date, Yes of today.

I read out the date accordingly and wrote it in a variable:

```
$Timestamp = ([datetime]::now).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
```

Now I want to read out all directory names which have got a Date < 1 Day and would like to process it in a foreach for further processing

Understandable?